# Remove whitespace only between two characters { and } in file

Tags: awk, sed, perl, whitespace

I have file with json values :

```
abc={"adf": "def",   "abc2":"def2", "abc3" : "def3" }
abc4= 1
abc = {hello : world, hello:"a"}
```

I want to remove whitespace from everywhere in between 
`{` and `}` and not any other place. Values don't have any spaces in my case.

```
abc={"adf":"def","abc2":"def2","abc3":"def3"}
abc4= 1
abc = {hello:world,hello:"a"}
```

How can i use sed, awk or perl or any tool to achieve this ?

Note: All values are in one line only. There is no multi line processing required.

Comment: also a duplicate of several other questions, but Stéphane's answer is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly Perl one-liner (works on Perl v5.24.1):

```
$ perl -pe 's/{.*?}/ $& =~ s, ,,gr /eg'  input
abc={"adf":"def","abc2":"def2","abc3":"def3"}
abc4= 1
abc = {hello:world,hello:"a"}
```

The outer substitution (`s///`) matches strings surrounded in braces, and replaces them by doing another substitution (`s,,,`) on the matched string.